# Moving a web part and its' document content without losing meta-data

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am attempting to move a web part (doc library) with calculated fields and a lookup field, from one site to another (all internal) and i can seem to acheive that without losing the documents' meta data. Can anyone help? I don't have access to powershell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125006/how-do-i-move-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-to-another-site-collection

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this:

1. go into `Library` settings (Library ribbon -> library settings)
2. go into `Save document library as template` link
3. fill the file name and description fields
4. check the `Include Content` checkbox
5. Click `Ok`

after that, you can go to the `list template gallery` and download the `.stp` file. you must go to the destination site and upload it to the list template gallery and make a new Document Library based on this template.

Comment: Will this retain calculated field data as well?  I have a contracts column with renewal dates, those are based on the added date to the list.

Comment: Yeah, why do you test it?